# Generate equation for one variable in terms of others

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, math, sequence

I have a particular data set where there are 3 different functions with 3 different variables:

```
x = 1
strLen_x = int(3**x + 0.25*(-3*(-1)**x + 3**x + 6)) # Function 1
y = 2
strLen_y = 2*y # Function 2
z = 3
strLen_z = 3*(z + 1 + (z//4)) # Function 3
# Expecting Function 4 in terms of 1, 2, and 3
```

The final output i.e `strLen_`... variable is nothing but a variable that is dependent of 3 different variables `x, y, and z`.
I'm trying to come up with a common equation where `strLen_xyz` is in terms of all the 3 variables (`x, y, z`).

Here's a table of the output with different values of `x, y, z`.
Note: `y > 1` and all the variables are positive integers.
[image: ![enter image description here]

Here, `Output` is the final value to be obtained.

Comment: It could be anything.  How about `strLen = strLen_x + strLen_y + strLen_z`?  If that's not what you want, then you need to specify the additional constraints that are missing from the question.  I'd say this question needs details and clarity.  For example, what do you mean when you say your previous approaches "failed"?

Comment: I have a feeling you would have fun with library [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). `import sympy as sym; x, y, z = sym.symbols('x y z'); strLen_x = sym.floor(3**x + 0.25*(-3*(-1)**x + 3**x + 6)); strLen_y = 2*y; strLen_z = 3*(z + 1 + (z//4))`

Comment: @TomKarzes I tried adding them, multiplying them, and dividing them. There's no specific constraint that I can identify. Should I provide you with a table of a few values with expected output?

Comment: @TomKarzes I added all the missing information. Also check the table.

Comment: What does the table have to do with `strLen_x` and the other two?

Comment: @KellyBundy the table is not related with `strLen_x` but is rather the input variable `x, y, z` itself. If you want, I can add one more image related with `strLen_x` and the other 2 that simulate the output.

Comment: Can you generate more table values?  It's tough to work out a 3-variable function without more sample values.

Comment: Sure, I'll update the table.

Comment: @TomKarzes updated, let me know if you need more or it suffices. Also thanks :)

Comment: You need a least squares fit.  I'd plot string length as a function of the three variables to see what assumed function might work.  Once I knew that, it'd be simple to fit a function that minimized the mean square error using least squares.

Comment: @duffymo can you please help me out with it.

Comment: Working on it.  Give me a second.  Do you know Python?

Comment: Yes @duffymo I know python

Answer (score 1):

Here's my complete answer.  This code does a multi-variable 2nd order polynomial regression on your data using [Scikit Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html):

```
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75650950/generate-equation-for-one-variable-in-terms-of-others

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures

def mse(y_test, predictions):
    return np.mean((y_test-predictions)**2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv('../resources/strlen.csv')

    cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns

    X = df[['x', 'y', 'z']].to_numpy()
    y = df[['len']].to_numpy()

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
    y_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(y)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1234)

    reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions = reg.predict(X_test)
    err = mse(y_test, predictions)
    print("Error       : ", err)
    print("Intercept   : ", reg.intercept_ )
    print("Coefficients: ", reg.coef_)

    y_pred_line = reg.predict(X)
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='x', y='len', hue='y', style='z')
    sns.lineplot(data=df, x='x', y='len')

    x_line = np.linspace(df.iloc[:, 0:3].min(axis=0), df.iloc[:, 0:3].max(axis=0), num=11)
    y_line = np.array(reg.intercept_[0] + np.matrix(x_line) * np.matrix(reg.coef_.transpose()))

    print('x_line: ', x_line, ' shape: ', x_line.shape)
    print('y_line: ', y_line, ' shape: ', y_line.shape)
    m1 = plt.plot(x_line[:, 0], y_line, color='red')

    plt.show()
```

Here is the .csv I created with your data:

```
x,y,z,len
12,6,6,12
12,4,12,16
36,4,6,10
36,4,24,60
36,4,6,10
36,8,9,160
102,6,6,102
306,4,9,80
306,4,24,240
306,8,24,7680
306,8,27,8960
306,10,21,19535
306,10,27,27345
912,10,21,97660
912,10,24,117190
912,10,36,175785
```

Fix the path to your file in the code and run it.

Here is the plot of the data.  The red line is the linear fit result:

[image]

I used a complete 2nd order polynomial: `y = a0 + a1*x + a2*y + a3*z + a4*x^2 + a5*x*y + a6*x*z + a7*y^2 + a8*y*z + a9*z*z`.

You can see the coefficients by printing `reg.coef_`.

Comment: Can you show the equation?

Comment: It's linear in the coefficients.  See y_line?

Comment: I see it in the code, but I don't see results.

Comment: I've edited the code.  You'll see a red line that will make it clear.